# How do you set up a Facebook app to ask to a user permission to allow publishing to their wall?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

We are trying to publish to a user's wall using the Facebook C# API using the following piece of code:

```
private Api _facebookAPI;
private ConnectSession _connectSession;

_connectSession = new ConnectSession(APPLICATION_KEY, SECRET_KEY);
_facebookAPI = new Api(_connectSession);

facebookAPI.Stream.Publish("testing 123");
```

We tried setting the application auth settings in Facebook by going to Settings -> Auth Dialog and altering these settings:

**User & Friend Permissions:** `publish_actions`

**Extended Permissions:** `publish_stream`

But when the user chooses to connect Facebook to our web app, the below message is displayed asking for the following permissions, obviously theses settings do not authorise us to post to their wall.

> **Access my basic information**
>
> Includes name, profile picture, gender, networks, user ID, list of friends, and any other information I've made public.

I want it to ask the user to allow publishing to the wall/feed, but we can't figure out how/where we set this up. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the login link or login button to prompt for the additional permissions. What is the login url you are using now?

I would recommend switching to the newer [Facebook C# SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com).  The [tutorial](http://blog.prabir.me/post/Facebook-CSharp-SDK-Writing-your-first-Facebook-Application.aspx) walks has an example of getting extended permissions.

Comment: Thanks for this, will have a look when back in the office tomorrow.

Comment: Finally got it working, that tutorial was really helpful, thanks!